# Add Razor Comment to Rendering Engine

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

At the moment [razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor) multiline comment code block do not render on SO as Comments:

[image]

It's extermely unlikely this code is used for anything other than a comment (at least that I am aware of).